# Unable to call ajax function but console.log and alert working of that JS file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

hello everyone working on PHP MVC. Facing issue while submitting form using ajax, in Network area of Inspect elements not able to see that perticular ajax being called. If i try to run console.log or alert in that JS then it's working fine. here is my JS code. Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button#applyLeave").click(function(){
        console.log('asgnduser');
        var leaveType = $("#leavetype").val();
        var leaveDate = $("#leavedate").val();
        var leaveTime = $("#leavetime").val();
        var leaveDateRange = $("#reservation").val();
        var leaveReason = $("#leavereason").val();
        console.log(leaveType + ' ' +leaveDate+ ' ' +leaveTime + ' ' +leaveDateRange + ' ' +leaveReason);
        alert(APP_URL + '/apply-leave');

        var dataString = 'leaveType='+ leaveType + '&leaveDate='+ leaveDate + '&leaveTime='+ leaveTime + '&leaveDateRange='+ leaveDateRange + '&leaveReason='+ leaveReason;
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: APP_URL + '/apply-leave',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    // console.log('Success: '+result);
                    // alert('Data Saved Successfully');
                    if (result == 'success') {
                        alert("Leave applied!!!");  
                        window.location.href = APP_URL + '/leaves';
                    }   
                },
                error: function(result){
                    // console.log('Error: '+result);
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: any error message on console?

Comment: No. there is not error message in console. @deepak

Answer (score 1):

I just tried out your code in code sandbox environment and it's working properly. If you don't see any requests going out then most likely your **button** or it's **ID** is not existing in the HTML.

Here's my example code sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-hugle-7rfnt?file=/src/index.js

You can do a compare with your code and see the difference.

Comment: Thanks @Veljko . But button and ID from html code is working. if they were not working then i wasn't able to get alert and console.log messages.

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry, I missed that. Weird... Then, if there's no difference I would assume it might be something related your version of JQuery? In the example I'm using 3.6.0. If all else fails, could you maybe use fetch instead of $.ajax for making a call? You would need to polyfil it for IE11 tho, if you need to support IE11.

Comment: Here's a great blog post to get started https://davidwalsh.name/fetch & polyfill for IE11 if needed https://github.com/github/fetch

Comment: Thanks @Veljko Blagojevic for helping but i got it. In inspect element Network tab recording of network log was turned off because of that wasn't able to see ajax there. it was silly mistake there. thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Did silly mistake over here. In inspect element Network tab recording of network log was turned off because of that wasn't able to see ajax there. Turning on I was able to see it.